# Field `alias_model` does not exist

Tags: inheritance, view, model, odoo, odoo-9

Trying to inherit model `note.note` in my form view but keep getting the error `Field "alias_model" does not exist`. I also inherit `note.note` in my models and my fields are added just fine.

Here is my view:

```
<record id="view_project_notes_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">Project Notes Form View</field>
      <field name="model">note.note</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.edit_project"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
          <xpath expr="//notebook/page[1]" position="after">
            <page string="Notes">
              <field name="title" placeholer="Title"/>
              <field name="tag_ids"/>
              <field name="memo"/>
            </page>
          </xpath>
        </data>
      </field>
    </record>
```

and my model:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class Notes(models.Model):
    _inherit = "note.note"

    title = fields.Char(string="Title")
    employee = fields.Many2many(string="Employee")
    modified_by = fields.Many2many(string="Modified By")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Post the stack trace please

Comment: I've actually figured out why it's not working. I can't reference a project view with a note model. I've attempted to solve this problem in a different question. Please see the post here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566652/how-do-i-add-multiple-models-to-one-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference one object's view with another object's model. So to expand the project.edit_project view, you have to reference model project.project. I still haven't figured out *how* to use note.note fields in the view. I've posted another question after trying to solve this problem: [How do I add multiple models to one view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566652/how-do-i-add-multiple-models-to-one-view)