# How do I add multiple models to one view?

Tags: odoo, view, models, odoo-9

I'm trying to use three different models in one view. I've created a new model that inherits the models which seems to work fine.

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class ProjectNote(models.Model):
    _name = "triangle.project.note"
    _inherit = ["note.note", "project.project", "triangle.note"]
```

My problem is in the view. I use my new model as the model and inherit a view from project.

```
<record id="view_project_notes_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">triangle.project.note.form</field>
      <field name="model">triangle.project.note</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.edit_project"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='privacy_visibility']" position="replace">
            <h2>
              <field name="title" placeholder="Title"/>
            </h2>
          </xpath>
        </data>
      </field>
    </record>
```

I don't get any errors but my field is not being added.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to open a `project.project` view and wondering why there is no field `title` in it: there can't be. You aren't extending the project view for model `project.project` but are defining a form view for your model `triangle.project.note` which inherits the project view.

So the project views are untouched, you've just created the first form view for your new model.

Comment: Ok, that does make sense to me. Do have any advice on how I can reference note.note fields in the project.edit_project view if this method is not going to work? The only solution I can think of is to create these fields in project.project also.

Comment: Yes, that will be the solution. Extend `project.project` with a `many2one` relation to `note.note` and inherit the view just normally for model `project.project`.